# Help evaluating Gamma integral with negative exponent

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, probability, stochastic-processes, levy-processes

The integral is:
$$\frac{1}{\Gamma{(1-\alpha)}}\int^\infty_0(1-e^{-\lambda y})e^{-y}y^{-(1+\alpha)} dy$$

where $\alpha\in(0,1)$ and $y,\lambda>0$.

I've tried using IBP, in which I get:
$$\frac{1}{\alpha\Gamma(1-\alpha)}[-e^{-y}y^{-\alpha}|^\infty_0 - \Gamma(1-\alpha)]$$

where I don't think its possible to evaluate the first term.

I've also just tried using the integral definition of Gamma, which I got a nice answer with but is invalid as the integral for $\Gamma(-\alpha) = \int^\infty_0e^{-y}y^{-\alpha-1}dy$  is not defined for negative numbers.

Where should I go from here?

Comment: I'm not sure you'll get a closed form for this. In series, it *should* be: $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n\cdot\lambda^n}{n!}\Gamma(n-\alpha)$$But good luck expressing that in a nicer fashion

Comment: The Gamma function is defined for non-negative reals, except non-negative integers.

Comment: @Andrei but would the integral representation not hold unless the real value is greater zero.

Comment: $$\int^\infty_0(1-e^{-\lambda y})e^{-y}y^{-(1+\alpha)} dy=-\frac1\alpha\int^\infty_0(e^{-y}-e^{-(\lambda+1) y}) d\big(y^{-\alpha}\big)$$
$$\overset{IBP}{=}-\frac1\alpha(e^{-y}-e^{-(\lambda+1) y}) y^{-\alpha}\,\bigg|_{y=0}^\infty-\frac1\alpha\int^\infty_0e^{-y}y^{-\alpha} dy+\frac{\lambda+1}\alpha\int^\infty_0e^{-(\lambda+1)y}y^{-\alpha} dy$$
$$=-\frac{\Gamma(1-\alpha)}\alpha+\frac{(1+\lambda)^\alpha\Gamma(1-\alpha)}\alpha,\quad\alpha<1$$

Comment: @Svyatoslav aren't we getting 0 in the denominator the first step after the IBP?

Comment: we get  at $\alpha<1$ and $y\to 0\quad(e^{-y}-e^{-(\lambda+1)y})y^{-\alpha}\to\frac{(\lambda+1-1)y}{y^\alpha}\to 0$

Comment: @Svyatoslav ahh yeah i used l'hospitals and it goes to zero. thanks!